# BadTokenException - BACK button

Tags: android

I know this topic was asked trillions of times throughout the web, but there is no one place answering it.

in my application, I have a welcome screen. when I run the program end-to-end everything is just fine - open/close activities and show dialogs of all sorts.
but, when I reach the welcome screen and from there pressing the **BACK** button - everything becomes messy:
1) the dialog i want to show cause BadTokenException (i'm using `this` and not `getApplicationContext()` ).

2) I tried use try/catch to catch the exception - and it really passed the `showDialog` line. but then, in the 2nd. run, when reaching a `showDialog` expression, it throws `IllegalStateException: View.com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44a59830 has already been added to the window manager`.

moreover, I understand that pressing HOME causes the onPause in the activity, while BACK causes onDestroy, but what goes wrong ??

i'm trying to fix that issue for **more than a week**, but with no success.
any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get you complete, But i think you need to do some stuff when you back button is pressed. So you can override you back button in you welcome screen activity or any other activity and add you code there

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // add you code here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: the only thing I can think of replacing the "add your code here" is calling finish(). the problem is - finish() cause the exact same behavior as the BACK button :(

Comment: finish() cause the exact same behavior as the BACK button!??? Finish() called when your activity is done and should be closed (Call onDestroy). Where back button action you can override and do as you wish

Comment: Labeeb, that's not what i meant in "cause the exact same behavior as the BACK button". what I meant was, if I tried calling finish in the main screen, I get the same error and exception thrown. what can I write in the BACK button? - pressing back from the main activity goes back the the HOME screen which is OK - but causes troubles on the way.